# How to use SpEL with hasRole to set html attribute?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

In Spring/Thymeleaf: I want to set attribute based on whether user has ROLE_A or not.

1. **I tried HTML below:**

`<section class="footer" ... th:someattr="#{hasRole('ROLE_A')} ? 'true' : 'false'">`

It always rendered as `<section class="footer" ... someattr="true">` regardless of whether user had ROLE_A or not:

2. **I tried also ${hasRole('ROLE_A')} ? 'true' : 'false' but that failed to work** ():

> SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 0): Method call: Method
>   hasRole(java.lang.String) cannot be found on
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELContextMapWrapper type

How to set an attribute to true|false depending on assigned authentication roles.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this is cause, because of the configuration of your project. So, let's do some changes and use the following code.

```
<section class="footer" ... th:someattr="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_A'')' ? 'true' : 'false'}">
```

To use `#authorization`, you will need to add the following dependency though, `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you are using `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>`, you won't need to add any version to your Thymeleaf Extras, since Spring Boot manages that for you. If not, try adding this version `<version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>`.

**Note:** If it doesn't work change it for `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5`, depending on your Spring version one will work and the other won't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```xml
<section class="footer" ... th:someattr="${#request.isUserInRole('A') ? 'true' : 'false'}">
```

(No "extras" needed.)